# Read integers until EOF in C

Tags: c, eof

I need to read all integers until the EOF. I'm trying this code and the problem is that the program doesn't detect the EOF and keeps running. What I need is to receive all the data and proceed to the next line of code automatically (the code works with pressing Ctrl-D after the input).

```
int x, sum = 0;

while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1) {
    sum += x;
}

if (feof(stdin)) {
    printf ( "SUM: %d\n", sum );
} else {
    printf("ERROR\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: You've done everything correctly and it behaves as it should behave. ^D sends the EOF when your stdin is a terminal, and it works with real files too.

Comment: Perhaps there's confusion about what EOF means for STDIN? It doesn't mean "blank line".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you want to specify EOF?

- `^D` is the way to do it in the terminal in Unix. In the Windows terminal, `^Z` does the same thing. `scanf` will return `-1` and `feof()` will be non zero. But any further input from stdin will fail too.
- Do you want to just hit the enter key?  If so, you have to check for that after `scanf`, otherwise the next call to `scanf` will read the linefeed and ignore it.
- If you type something that is neither white space nor a number, `scanf` will return `0` and leave the unmatched character in the input stream.  Your program will print `ERROR`.  Is this what is happening?